# how do I add two variables by javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

the code below concatenates the two variables instead of adding them to get one value. any help on how to correct this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function calculatetotal1() {


         var mal = document.getElementById('<%=txtadults.ClientID%>').value;

        var child = document.getElementById('<%=txtnumchilderen.ClientID%>').value;

        var res = mal + child;
        document.getElementById('<%=txttotal.ClientID%>').value = res;

    }
```

Comment: `.value` always returns a string, hence `+` concatenates them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Number()` to convert values to number

```
function calculatetotal1() {
        var mal = Number(document.getElementById('<%=txtadults.ClientID%>').value);

        var child = Number(document.getElementById('<%=txtnumchilderen.ClientID%>').value);

        var res = mal + child;
        document.getElementById('<%=txttotal.ClientID%>').value = res;

}
```

Comment: this works great but i have one more issue, the result which is displayed in text box by id txttotal gets disappear after postback say after clicking the submit button how do i fixed that too thanks in advance

Comment: thank you very much I think I have figured it out: my text box was read only so i just cleared that read only property

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have no background with asp.net so I'm not able to tell you what the problem is.Glad to hear that you figured it out. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

Parsing both variables as float should to the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function calculatetotal1() {


     var mal = document.getElementById('<%=txtadults.ClientID%>').value;

    var child = document.getElementById('<%=txtnumchilderen.ClientID%>').value;

    var res = parseFloat(mal) + parseFloat(child);
    document.getElementById('<%=txttotal.ClientID%>').value = res;

}
```

Comment: this works great but i have one more issue, the result which is displayed in text box by id txttotal gets disappear after postback say after clicking the submit button how do i fixed that too thanks in advance –

Comment: thank you very much I think I have figured it out: my text box was read only so i just cleared that read only property

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert those values to number before adding them using the `+` operator. There are several ways of doing that, but you can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` for this:

```
var mal = document.getElementById('<%=txtadults.ClientID%>').value;
var child = document.getElementById('<%=txtnumchilderen.ClientID%>').value;

var res = parseFloat(mal) + parseFloat(child);
document.getElementById('<%=txttotal.ClientID%>').value = res;
```

Comment: this works great but i have one more issue, the result which is displayed in text box by id txttotal gets disappear after postback say after clicking the submit button how do i fixed that too thanks in advance –

Comment: thank you very much I think I have figured it out: my text box was read only so i just cleared that read only property

Answer (score 0):

You are getting input values from textbox and the datatype of textbox value by default is string. So your current code is just considering it as string and doing concatenation.
Try using [parseFloat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) function for both values.
Try the following code.

```
function calculatetotal1() {


     var mal = parseFloat (document.getElementById('<%=txtadults.ClientID%>').value);

    var child = parseFloat (document.getElementById('<%=txtnumchilderen.ClientID%>').value);

    var res =  mal + child;
    document.getElementById('<%=txttotal.ClientID%>').value = res;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, + operator acts like concatenation and add the values
Like below

```
Var x = 2 + 3 // will be 5
Var y = '2' + 3 // will be 23 as string
```